# ADFS 2016 OAuth: Compress JWT?

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth, jwt, load-balancing, adfs

We are using ADFS 2016 as our OAuth authorization server.  It is returning the OAuth access token as a JWT.  ADFS has been configured to return the groups the Active Directory account is a member of.  Everything is working properly from a token issuance standpoint.  However, we have recently run into issue where the `Authorization` HTTP header that contains the JWT on subsequent RESTful service calls is too large.  The Amazon ALBs that we are using as load balancers have a hard limit on the size of a header value and are rejecting the request.

I know that the *contents* of the JWT can be customized through some configuration within ADFS.  Is compression also an option?  If we were able to compress the token at issuance time it would reduce the size enough to go through the load balancers.

Has anyone else encountered something like this?  If so, how did you get around it?  I can't imagine we're the only shop that has encountered large header sizes with OAuth/JWTs.

Comment: Can you use HTTP/2 and enable Header Compression?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a compress option.

Are you using memberOf?

Can you use the Group claim rule to pass just the groups you need?

You can also use claims rules to make smaller claims e.g.

change http://... /claims/givenname to just http://company/gn.